# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ReconnectOnErrorManagement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- ruby 2.7.1
- rails 6.0.3

config/application.rb

```
    # # for aurora failover bug
    config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Executor,
                                    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ReconnectOnErrorManagement
```

then

```
rails c
```

I got

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ReconnectOnErrorManagement (NameError)
```

I have no idea.

Comment: What did you do before it happened, any changes to the code (e.g. upgrading rails from an older version to 6.0)?

Comment: I'm upgrading rails from an 5.x to 6.0.

Comment: Actually I made new project of rails 6.x, then moved source codes which run on rails 5.x to the project.

Comment: Are you using the airbrake gem? (Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867028/uninitialized-constant-activerecordconnectionadaptersconnectionmanagement-n)

Comment: I dont think so. I can't find `airbrake ` in my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock...